# Is it possible to include internal/external storage directories such as the Android Downloads or Documents folders in the Gradle Source Sets?

Tags: android, gradle, directory, path

So I am developing an Android App that incorporates a Python Interpreter, one from Chaquopy, and one of the requirements inorder to run any scripts is for the .py files with the code to be included or rather be in any of the default or predefined source set directories/folders. This works well if the .py files are included/bundled in with the APK file but this presents a challenge in that the files now become read-only files at run-time since they cannot be modified when the app is running or has been installed.

The app is to allow the users to create, save code, and read from .py files that they would have created, but then the challenge now is that the files will be included in the directories such as the Android Downloads or Documents folder or the apps' internal files folder and as such they cannot be run in the application since it requires that they be saved in any of the source set directories, as the interpreter will look for them there.

I have tried to incorporate the 3 directories in this way, using their respective paths `

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        python.srcDir "/src/main/assets" //this works for asset files, the rest don't

        python.srcDir sdk_gphone_x86/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.tendaik.chaquo_trial_2/files"
 
        pyrthon.srcDir "/storage/emulated/0/document"

        python.srcDir "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.tendaik.chaquo_trial_2/files"

        python.srcDir "storage/emulated/0/Android/download"
        

    }
```

`

But all to no avail unfortunately, as this only succeeds in creating and including these directories in the project as project directories instead of accessing the directories from the internal storage, as shown in the image. All premissions to access the folders/directories are included in the Manifest file as well

[image: directory path sourcesets]

How then can I include the internal storage directories as part of the source sets, if it is possible?

Comment: Your development machine and your Android device usually are two distinct things. If so, your development machine does not have access to files on any of the ~3 billion Android devices out there. Hence, Gradle build scripts run on your development machine cannot reference files on any of those Android devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can't list Android device paths in the build.gradle file, because that file only controls the build process: it has no effect on the runtime value of [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path).

However, there are various ways you can dynamically load Python code at runtime:

- If the code is in the [*internal* storage directory](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#android-os), then you can simply add its location to `sys.path`.
- As it says in [this FAQ](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/faq.html#faq-sdcard), the *external* storage folder (which contains Downloads and so on) cannot be accessed directly in recent versions of Android, so adding it to `sys.path` won't work. Instead, by following the example in the FAQ, you can use the system file picker to get the content of any file, and then do whatever you want with that content, such as passing it to [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec).